# Ansible: Extracting IP address from a CIDR( 192.168.21.x/24)

Tags: ansible, cidr

I have a variable name something like this defined in json format.

"zxc_address" : "192.168.21.x/24"

and i need to extract the IP address part(192.168.21.x) using ansible(yaml code)
what is the simple solution for that? can it be done using ansible filters. if yes then how?

Thanks,
VM

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Ansible >=1.9 it is possible to use a filter for this:

```
{{ '192.0.2.1/24' | ipaddr('address') }}
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#ip-address-filter).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
{{ zxc_address.split("/")[0] }}
```